# Creating a scatterplot with one x and multiple y values

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, lattice

I have data of the form:

```
[x]  [y1] [y2]
1    0.9   1
2    2.0   2
3    3.1   3
```

Where (x,y1) are actual values and y2 is a prediction for y1 based on a linear model estimated on another set of data. (x, y1, y2) are in a dataframe DT. How can I make a scatterplot using xyplot that graphs x on the x-axis and y1 and y2 on the y-axis but with different colors?

I was able to do this in ggplot using the following code, but think it looks much less nice than using the xyplot() command, and am wondering if I can use xyplot / lattice in this case.

```
ggplot(DT, aes(x)) + geom_point(aes(y=y1), color="red") + geom_point(aes(y=y2), color = "green")
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A simple reproducible example would be great to get and idea of what you currently have for data.  It makes it easier for us to help you.  if you have a data frame named DT, try `dput(DT[1:10,])` for a nice output that will let us help you

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you need to make your data tidy for `ggplot` to be able to easily do what you want. Since you didn't give us an actual example to work with, I am generating some sample data then tidying it (note, using `dplyr` and `tidyr` here)

```
exampleData <-
  iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Length)

exampleData

toPlot <-
  exampleData %>%
  gather(sepalMeasure, size, -Petal.Length)
```

Then, you can use the generated `sepalMeasure` column to color the points. For your data, you would have something that distinguished the predicted and actual points.

```
toPlot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length
             , y = size
             , col = sepalMeasure)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I apologize for not sharing my actual data; it's organized as a dataframe with three columns, x, y1, and y2 and about 500 rows. Right now the predicted points are a separate variable (y2) from the actual points (y1), as opposed to having one y variable and a variable like SepalMeasure to distinguish groupings/colors. On the example above, it would be as if there were two different variables for size, one for each sepalMeasure. Is it possible to use a similar syntax for the graph in that case?

Comment: `exampleData` is exactly like you describe your data. I used `gather` to create `sepalMeasure` & `size`. You will need to do the same with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot 2 y variables using `y1 + y2` in the formula

```
 d=data.frame(x=1:9,y1=2:10,y2=3:11)
 library(lattice)
 xyplot(y1+y2~x,d)
```

EDIT:
You can add a legend with

```
 xyplot(y1+y2~x,d,auto.key=TRUE)
```

Use other `lattice` features to control colors, labels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with()`, `plot()` and `points()` functions of the base plot package in R:

```
with(datatable,plot(X,Y1))
with(datatable,points(X,Y2))
with(datatable,points(X,Y3))
```